# Access multiple arrays from JSON using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

This is my function to fetch the array.

```
  $scope.getclinicofuser = function()
    {
            var dataParameter =  {
                                    "primaryEmailId":$scope.data1.email                     
                                 }

                    $http({
                    url:  "/cms/api/user/getUserClinic",
                    method: "POST",
                    headers :{'Content-Type': 'application/json','Accept': 'application/json' },
                    data: dataParameter
                    }) .success(function(response) {

                    $scope.DomainName = response;
                 console.log($scope.DomainName);
                    });
    };

});
```

**Here is the api call response**

```
{
    "clinicNames": [2]
        0:  {
            "clinicName": "testing"
            "DomainName": "Aman.example.com"
            "primaryEmailId": "example@gmail.com"
        }-
        1:  {
            "clinicName": "test-clinic"
            "DomainName": "raman.example.com"
            "primaryEmailId": "example@gmail.com"
        }-
        -
        "status_code": "success"
}
```

**My html tag**

```
<li ng-repeat="response in DomainName">{{root.clinicNames}}</li>
```

Now what i want to do is to display BOTH DomainName  in HTML i had a hussel with HTML ng-repeat tags but still no clues what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<li ng-repeat="response in DomainName.clinicNames track by $index">{{response.DomainName}}</li>
```

Comment: damn man it works...!! just tell me one thing... mujhe controller mai for each lagane ki jarurat kyu nai pari? isko ng-repeat se kaise handle kar lia?

Comment: bro `ng-repeat` will work same as each loop. Ye template me iterate karne ke kaam aata h.

Comment: thanks bhai... india ka naam ucha kar dia aaj tumne :D :D